# I can't make Admob Banner Ads to work in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I have attached the unity file at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YACcaZ6dGDwWrcIryeo08SligeJIsbbF/view?usp=sharing
Can somebody explain to me why I can't make Admob banner Ads to work in Unity?

This is the code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
public class AdsManager : MonoBehaviour {

private BannerView bannerView;


public void Start()
{
    this.RequestBanner();

}

private void RequestBanner()
{

    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-5910635131088321/3620740570";


    // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
    bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);

    // Create an empty ad request.
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

    // Load the banner with the request.
    bannerView.LoadAd(request);
  }
}
```

The problem that I have is that I made an app in unity and now I have spent more time trying to make an Admob banner to show in that app that I have spent making that app
Could you please look in that unity package and tell me why the Admob banner dosen't show any ad?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the provided Events. Once you use the event, you'll be able to know the real cause. 
The Ads might not be available for your region. Also when you create Ads ID, ads just don't get served right after you create. So you need to wait or use an old Ad ID. The best solution is to debug your project with test ads. 
Kindly have a look at the reference demo script that can help you get the event's data.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/blob/master/samples/HelloWorld/Assets/Scripts/GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.cs
Confirm and check your logs for further insight.

```
#region Banner callback handlers

public void HandleAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLoaded event received");
}

public void HandleAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
{
    MonoBehaviour.print("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: " + args.Message);
}

public void HandleAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");
}

public void HandleAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdClosed event received");
}
```

Comment: The  Ads ID is old and also it doesn't work with test id

Comment: can you share logs ?
what do you get in
    public void HandleAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLoaded event received");
    }

    public void HandleAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: " + args.Message);
    }